# Trying to make sections of sprite change colour, but whole sprite changes instead

Tags: python, pygame, sprite, pygame-surface

I have a few sprites in my game that need specific parts to be able to change colour.

My process I am trying to to have a pure white sprite image that is transparent everywhere the colour does not need to be. I am blitting a coloured square on top of that, and then that on top of the main sprite, however the main sprite then changes colour everywhere, but while respecting the main sprite transparency. The part that confuses me most is that the masked colour image does look correct when I put it on the main screen.

```py
# Load main sprite and mask sprite
        self.image = pygame.image.load("Enemy.png").convert_alpha()
        self.mask = pygame.image.load("EnemyMask.png").convert_alpha()

# Create coloured image the size of the entire sprite
        self.coloured_image = pygame.Surface([self.width, self.height])
        self.coloured_image.fill(self.colour)

# Mask off the coloured image with the transparency of the masked image, this part works
        self.masked = self.mask.copy()
        self.masked.blit(self.coloured_image, (0, 0), None, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)

# Put the masked image on top of the main sprite
        self.image.blit(self.masked, (0, 0), None, pygame.BLEND_MULT)
```

Enemy.png [image: enemy.png]

EnemyMask.png (It's white so can't be seen)
[image: EnemyMask.png]

Masked colour [Masked Colour](https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1M_mLiTWast0E68H5UKInmUxO95k8_woR=w1164-h915-iv1)

Final Failed Sprite [Failed Sprite](https://lh3.google.com/u/0/d/1gV6WWdnRV458Tatgn2PMQeXp4EeY17ti=w1164-h915-iv1)

Can't post images, not enough reputation

I get no error, but only the white part of the shield is supposed to be green

Comment: I can't see your images, they require a Google Account.  (Except the first image.)

Comment: I just changed something, curious to see if the second image now works for you. `self.colour` doesn't have an alpha, but is also only solid colour

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`self.image` is the loaded image, where you want to change specific regions by a certain color and `self.mask` is a mask which defines the regions.

And you create an image `masked`, which contains the regions which are specified in `mask` tinted in a specific color.

So all you've to do is to `.blit` the tinted mask (`masked`) on the `image` without any `special_flags` set:

```py
self.image.blit(self.masked, (0, 0))
```

See the example, where the red rectangle is changed to a blue rectangle:

<kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ChangeColorOfSurfaceArea](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ChangeColorOfSurfaceArea#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ChangeColorOfSurfaceArea-3](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ChangeColorOfSurfaceArea-3#main.py)</kbd>

Sprite: [image]

Mask: [image]

[image]

```py
import pygame

def changColor(image, maskImage, newColor):
    colouredImage = pygame.Surface(image.get_size())
    colouredImage.fill(newColor)
    
    masked = maskImage.copy()
    masked.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    masked.blit(colouredImage, (0, 0), None, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)

    finalImage = image.copy()
    finalImage.blit(masked, (0, 0), None)

    return finalImage

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((404, 84))

image = pygame.image.load('avatar64.png').convert_alpha()
maskImage = pygame.image.load('avatar64mask.png').convert_alpha()

colors = []
for hue in range (0, 360, 60):
    colors.append(pygame.Color(0))
    colors[-1].hsla = (hue, 100, 50, 100)

images = [changColor(image, maskImage, c) for c in colors]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
nextColorTime = 0
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        window.blit(image, (10 + i * 64, 10))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```

Comment: Thank you! I'm not entirely clear one why that was the problem, but it has worked. Given this solution I'll need to make the mask have the greyscale detail of my full sprite.