# Changing ememy's color to show that it is aking damage?

Tags: python, pygame

I am working on a code in which i need help to change the body color of my enemy while it takes damage! #Like_minecraft. Do i need to add different images to do that or it can be done with coding?? And i even want the goblin(enemy) to show the animation of hitting the player which i have the images I just want the enemy to show that enemy ehen the player is near 2 or 3 px from him and go near him after the player is in 5 or 6 px radius near  the goblin!Help!Iknow this is kinda long but still!
This is my enemy class:

```
class enemy(object):
    walkRight = [pygame.image.load('R1E.png'), pygame.image.load('R2E.png'), pygame.image.load('R3E.png'), pygame.image.load('R4E.png'), pygame.image.load('R5E.png'), pygame.image.load('R6E.png'), pygame.image.load('R7E.png'), pygame.image.load('R8E.png'), pygame.image.load('R9E.png'), pygame.image.load('R10E.png'), pygame.image.load('R11E.png')]
    walkLeft = [pygame.image.load('L1E.png'), pygame.image.load('L2E.png'), pygame.image.load('L3E.png'), pygame.image.load('L4E.png'), pygame.image.load('L5E.png'), pygame.image.load('L6E.png'), pygame.image.load('L7E.png'), pygame.image.load('L8E.png'), pygame.image.load('L9E.png'), pygame.image.load('L10E.png'), pygame.image.load('L11E.png')]
```

in this from 8 to end is attack images:

```
    def __init__(self, x, y, width, height, end):
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.width = width
        self.height = height
        self.end = end
        self.path = [self.x, self.end]
        self.walkCount = 0
        self.vel = 3
        self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
        self.health = 10
        self.visible = True

    def draw(self,win):
        self.move()
        if self.visible:
            if self.walkCount + 1 >= 33:
                self.walkCount = 0

            if self.vel > 0:
                win.blit(self.walkRight[self.walkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            else:
                win.blit(self.walkLeft[self.walkCount //3], (self.x, self.y))
                self.walkCount += 1
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50, 10))
            pygame.draw.rect(win, (0,128,0), (self.hitbox[0], self.hitbox[1] - 20, 50 - (5 * (10 - self.health)), 10))
            self.hitbox = (self.x + 17, self.y + 2, 31, 57)
            #pygame.draw.rect(win, (255,0,0), self.hitbox,2) #It makes a rectangle arount the goblin

    def move(self):
        if self.vel > 0:
            if self.x + self.vel < self.path[1]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0
        else:
            if self.x - self.vel > self.path[0]:
                self.x += self.vel
            else:
                self.vel = self.vel * -1
                self.walkCount = 0

    def hit(self):
        if self.health > 0:
            self.health -= 1
        else:
            self.visible = False
        

def redrawGameWindow():
    win.blit(bg, (0,0))
    text = font.render('Score : ' + str(score), 1, (0,0,0))
    win.blit(text, (201, 12))
    man.draw(win)
    goblin.draw(win)
    for bullet in bullets:
        bullet.draw(win)
    
    pygame.display.update()
```

Answer (score 3):

You actually need an image

[image]

and a mask image. The mak image has just 2 color, black and white. The white areas of the mask define the areas in the image whose color needs to be changed:

[image]

The following function uses a [`pygame.Surface`](https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/surface.html) object `image`,  `pygame.Surface` object `maskImage` and a color (`newColor`), to create a new Surface. In the new Surface the color of the regions which are defined by `maskImage`, is changed to `newColor`:

```py
def changColor(image, maskImage, newColor):
    colouredImage = pygame.Surface(image.get_size())
    colouredImage.fill(newColor)
    
    masked = maskImage.copy()
    masked.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    masked.blit(colouredImage, (0, 0), None, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)

    finalImage = image.copy()
    finalImage.blit(masked, (0, 0), None)

    return finalImage
```

See also:

- [Is it possible to change sprite colours in Pygame?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56209634/is-it-possible-to-change-sprite-colours-in-pygame)
- [Trying to make sections of sprite change colour, but whole sprite changes instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58385570/trying-to-make-sections-of-sprite-change-colour-but-whole-sprite-changes-instea)

---

Minimal example: <kbd>[[image] repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ChangeColorOfSurfaceArea-3](https://repl.it/@Rabbid76/PyGame-ChangeColorOfSurfaceArea-3#main.py)</kbd>

[image]

```py
import pygame

def changColor(image, maskImage, newColor):
    colouredImage = pygame.Surface(image.get_size())
    colouredImage.fill(newColor)
    
    masked = maskImage.copy()
    masked.set_colorkey((0, 0, 0))
    masked.blit(colouredImage, (0, 0), None, pygame.BLEND_RGBA_MULT)

    finalImage = image.copy()
    finalImage.blit(masked, (0, 0), None)

    return finalImage

pygame.init()
window = pygame.display.set_mode((404, 84))

image = pygame.image.load('avatar64.png').convert_alpha()
maskImage = pygame.image.load('avatar64mask.png').convert_alpha()

colors = []
for hue in range (0, 360, 60):
    colors.append(pygame.Color(0))
    colors[-1].hsla = (hue, 100, 50, 100)

images = [changColor(image, maskImage, c) for c in colors]

clock = pygame.time.Clock()
nextColorTime = 0
run = True
while run:
    clock.tick(60)
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            run = False

    window.fill((255, 255, 255))
    for i, image in enumerate(images):
        window.blit(image, (10 + i * 64, 10))
    pygame.display.flip()

pygame.quit()
exit()
```